# Linux кастомизация приглашения консоли

Tags: linux, shell

Возможно ли средствами `Bourne shell` (`sh`, *не bash*) реализовать примерно следующее:

- Если перед выполнением некой команды последней нажатой клавишей был Enter, то...
- Иначе если последней нажатой клавишей не был Enter, то...

Бэкграунд вопроса: у меня есть эстетическая проблема с кастомной строкой приглашения. Она выглядит, в идеале, вот так:
[image: То, что задумано и происходит в лучшем случае.]

А в общем случае вот так:
[image: То, что происходит чаще всего.]

Общий случай случается каждый раз, когда я дополняю команды клавишей *Tab*, перебираю историю стрелками или когда по какой-то другой причине происходит перерисовка строки приглашения без запуска команды с переносом на строку вниз. *(Например, при загрузке системы, когда демон fbcondecor рисует фоновую картинку в консоли. Из-за этого меня "приветствует" консоль с двумя наползающими друг на друга строками приветствия вместо аккуратной одной.)*

Соответственно я хочу в строке приветствия реализовать алгоритм, который бы в зависимости от того, был ли перед текущим приглашением нажат Enter или нет, переводил бы указатель на строку вверх, либо оставался на текущей позиции. **С помощью чего я могу это сделать?**

Либо каким-то иным способом реализовать задуманное. Мне в голову приходит только так, но, может, есть и другие пути. Я смутно их тоже представляю, но они включают в себя такие костыли...

Comment: а при чём тут linux?

Comment: кто занимается интерактивной обработкой вашего ввода? в `bash` по умолчанию это делает библиотека `readline`. а в вашем *shell-е*?